# ASP Datatables(jquery plugin) with more pages causes validation false

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, datatables

I start using [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) for already existing asp:GridView. Every row in gridview has textbox with asp:RangeValidator. **Everything works fine until Datatable has more than one page**. At this situation the Page is not valid by default. So buttons which causes validation and saves the form is not firing.

I localize problem at ScriptResource.axd which fail at *document.getElementById(id)* because control has null value, despite of that control exist at page and has the correct ID.

Any idea?

Thanks